# При установки Ruby выдает ошибку

Tags: ruby

```
 _____       _           _____           _        _ _         ___
|  __ \     | |         |_   _|         | |      | | |       |__ \
| |__) |   _| |__  _   _  | |  _ __  ___| |_ __ _| | | ___ _ __ ) |
|  _  / | | | '_ \| | | | | | | '_ \/ __| __/ _` | | |/ _ \ '__/ /
| | \ \ |_| | |_) | |_| |_| |_| | | \__ \ || (_| | | |  __/ | / /_
|_|  \_\__,_|_.__/ \__, |_____|_| |_|___/\__\__,_|_|_|\___|_||____|
                    __/ |           _
                   |___/          _|_ _  __   | | o __  _| _     _
                                   | (_) |    |^| | | |(_|(_)\^/_>

   1 - MSYS2 base installation
   2 - MSYS2 system update
   3 - MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain

Which components shall be installed? If unsure press ENTER [1,2,3] 1

MSYS2 seems to be unavailable
Verify integrity of msys2-x86_64-20161025.exe ... OK  
Run the MSYS2 installer ...  
C:\Users\46AD~1\AppData\Local\Temp/msys2-x86_64-20161025.exe  
 Failed  
Installation failed: MSYS2 installer failed

   1 - MSYS2 base installation
   2 - MSYS2 system update
   3 - MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain

Which components shall be installed? If unsure press ENTER [] 1

MSYS2 seems to be unavailable
Verify integrity of msys2-x86_64-20161025.exe ... OK
Run the MSYS2 installer ...
C:\Users\46AD~1\AppData\Local\Temp/msys2-x86_64-20161025.exe
Failed
Installation failed: MSYS2 installer failed

   1 - MSYS2 base installation
   2 - MSYS2 system update
   3 - MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain

Which components shall be installed? If unsure press ENTER []
```

Comment: Пожалуйста замените картинку текстом.

Comment: А ОС у вас какая? Винда?

Comment: 10 Windows на данный момент. Погуглил и решил установить программу MSYS2 вот после нее началась установка Ruby. Отпишусь в конце установки. Только установка станная какая-та.

Comment: Как показывает практика, руби-разработка и винда очень плохо совместимы. Очень рекомендую поднять виртуалку с линуксом или поставить его второй системой.

Comment: Руби установил, но теперь 2 проблема.

Comment: ERROR:  Error installing sass:
        The last version of ffi (< 2, >= 0.5.0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.9.18. Try installing it with `gem install ffi -v 1.9.18` and then running the current command again
        ffi requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0. The current ruby version is 2.5.0. Что делать с этим ? Это я пытаюсь установить препроцессор sass